# one input few numbers , how calculate SUM?

Tags: javascript, html

I am really new at this so please bear with me.

How can I calculate sum of numbers from one input field using JavaScript and write the result under button? I know how to make it with input for every number or with prompts where user enter numbers. But how can I do it using only one input? How to make a function which calculate result?

[image]

so `sum = 20.15` because `4+6+10.15 = 20.15`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can `split()` the value by comma then use `reduce()` to get the sum:

```js
function getSum(){
  var sum = document.getElementById('txt').value.split(',').reduce((a,c) => a + Number(c), 0);
  console.log(sum);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="4,6,10.15" id="txt"/>
<input type="button" value="Calculate Sum" onclick="getSum()"/>
```

Comment: @Kathius, please notice the update in `getElementById()` instead of `querySelector()` ....thanks.

Comment: yes, queryselector is new for me so i was a bit confused for a moment but still i got it after research, but with getElementById() everything is clear right now, thanks a lot ! <3 stackoverflow community :)

Answer (score 0):

From the input.value you have the following string : "4,6,10,15"
You then need to parse it as following :

```
let myString = input.value;
let myArrayValue = myString.split(",");
let sum = 0;
myArrayValue.forEach( (e) => {
  sum = sum + Number(e)
})
console.log(String(sum))
```